# Fixing python error in QGIS Freehand raster georeferencer plugin?

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins, georeferencing

I am using QGIS 2.8.9 stable release in the 32bit form on a Windows 7 64 bit compatible PC. I want to use the Freehand raster georeferencer plugin. It installs without difficulty but when I try to open a raster in the plugin I get the error code 'An error has occurred while executing python code' and this readout:

raceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/hpethen/.qgis2/python/plugins\FreehandRasterGeoreferencer\freehandrastergeoreferencer.py", line 190, in addLayer
    self.createFreehandRasterGeoreferencerLayer()
  File "C:/Users/hpethen/.qgis2/python/plugins\FreehandRasterGeoreferencer\freehandrastergeoreferencer.py", line 201, in createFreehandRasterGeoreferencerLayer
    layer = FreehandRasterGeoreferencerLayer(self, imagePath , imageName, screenExtent)
  File "C:/Users/hpethen/.qgis2/python/plugins\FreehandRasterGeoreferencer\freehandrastergeoreferencer_layer.py", line 46, in **init**
    self.initializeLayer(screenExtent)
  File "C:/Users/hpethen/.qgis2/python/plugins\FreehandRasterGeoreferencer\freehandrastergeoreferencer_layer.py", line 157, in initializeLayer
    self.resetScale(sw, sh)
  File "C:/Users/hpethen/.qgis2/python/plugins\FreehandRasterGeoreferencer\freehandrastergeoreferencer_layer.py", line 166, in resetScale
    wratio = sw / iw
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero

Python version:
2.7.4 (default, Apr  6 2013, 19:54:46) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]

QGIS version:
2.8.9-Wien Wien, 26c3ece

Python path: ['C:/PROGRA~2/QGISWI~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing', 'C:/PROGRA~2/QGISWI~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python', u'C:/Users/hpethen/.qgis2/python', u'C:/Users/hpethen/.qgis2/python/plugins', 'C:/PROGRA~2/QGISWI~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISWI~1\bin\python27.zip', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\DLLs', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\plat-win', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISWI~1\bin', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\markupsafe-0.23-py2.7-win32.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\python_dateutil-2.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytz-2014.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win32.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode', u'C:/Users/hpethen/.qgis2//python', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISWI~1\apps\qgis-ltr\python\plugins\fTools\tools', 'C:/Users/hpethen/Documents/Docs/Work/Teaching/EES_FieldSchool']

I have had previous releases of QGIS on here. Is it possible that there is some conflict? Is this a 32bit vs 64 bit issue or is there something else I'm missing.

Answer (score 4):

I completely uninstalled all the QGIS I could find on my computer and then reinstalled the 64bit version of QGIS 2.8.9 stable release. Once I had done that the plugin worked properly.

I think this problem either relates to have remains of more than one verison of QGIS on the computer, or it was a 32bit issue.

The plugin works perfectly and is brilliant.